# use generic Queue in Mono 3.28 under ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

I am using Mono 3.2.8 under Ubuntu 13.10. (The same problem crops up even when I used Mono 2.10.8). I cannot create a Queue object. I have added the System.Collections.Generic in the using statements.

I have tried creating the Queue using the following code:

```
private Queue<string> Message
```

or:

```
private System.Collections.Generic.Queue<string> Message
```

I have noticed that in the tooltip the Queue object does not come up (List comes up). The compiler error is:

```
"Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Queue' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246) (Linux-sim)"
```

Do I need to download any mode modules?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem. I had to add a reference to "System."

Somehow MonoDevelop didn't include the default reference to "System" when I created my project.

Answer (score 0):

The folllowing test program JustWorks on Ubuntu 13.10:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<int>();
        queue.Enqueue(1);
        queue.Enqueue(2);
        queue.Enqueue(3);
        queue.Enqueue(4);
        queue.Enqueue(5);
        foreach(int i in queue)
            System.Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

System details:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2)
Linux basehews 3.11.0-18-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 18 21:11:14 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dpkg --get-selections | grep mono` is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/7090621/

I can only assume you used the wrong compiler/options. I used

```
gmcs test.cs
```

or

```
dmcs test.cs
```

Both work.

Comment: I managed to get the Queue class working when compiling and running from the terminal but the error now persists when using MonoDevelop. What settings could I have wrong? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea. What command does monodevelop use to build? (See Build Output pane)